# How to correctly analyse this dataset (Linear Mixed Models)

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, mixed-model

I have a dataset of measurements taken at night (Var_night) and during the day (Var_day).

Each subject is assessed during several days (see column Day) and subjects have different demographic characteristics (Age,Sex,BMI) and they belong to different clinical groups (A,B,C).

```
IDX    Group    Subject_id    Age      Sex       BMI    Day    Var_night    Var_day
___    _____    __________    ___    ________    ___    ___    _________    _______

 1     'A'      1             60     'Male'      28     1      44           48     
 2     'A'      1             60     'Male'      28     2      43           47     
 3     'A'      1             60     'Male'      28     3      44           48     
 4     'A'      1             60     'Male'      28     4      34           38     
 5     'C'      2             50     'Male'      26     1      46           50     
 6     'C'      2             50     'Male'      26     2      43           47     
 7     'C'      2             50     'Male'      26     3      45           49     
 8     'B'      3             66     'Female'    25     1      66           70     
 9     'B'      3             66     'Female'    25     2      64           68     
10     'B'      3             66     'Female'    25     3      66           70
```

This table is just an example of a bigger dataset.
I would like to show that Var_night and Var_day are linked (i.e. an increase in Var_night causes an increase in Var_day).

Please note that the first 4 rows (idx:1-4) represent subject 1 (assessed for 4 days), rows idx:5-7 represent subject 2 (assessed for 3 days) etc. Is it a repeated measures problem?

If necessary I can discretize Var_day (response) using an ordinal variable in order to perform logistic regression.

Could you please suggest me how to proceed with the statistical analysis?
How should I approach this problem?

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion of Jonas I fit the model (using matlab, but it should be the same)

```
lme = fitlme(mytable,'Var_day ~ 1 + Var_night + GOLD + MMRC + Sex + Age + BMI + (1|IDX)');
```

(please not that I added the fixed effect GOLD and MMRC, not present in the first table)

and I get the result:

```
lme = 


Linear mixed-effects model fit by ML

Model information:
    Number of observations            3298
    Fixed effects coefficients          12
    Random effects coefficients        805
    Covariance parameters                2

Formula:
    Var_day ~ 1 + Var_night + GOLD + MMRC + Sex + Age + BMI + (1|IDX)

Model fit statistics:
    AIC      BIC      LogLikelihood    Deviance
    45978    46063    -22975           45950   

Fixed effects coefficients (95% CIs):
    Name                 Estimate    SE         tStat       DF      pValue         Lower       Upper   
    '(Intercept)'          3105.5     112.07      27.711    3286    4.5045e-152      2885.8      3325.2
    'Var_night'              -0.36272    0.05064     -7.1627    3286     9.7153e-13    -0.46201    -0.26343
    'GOLD_GOLD 2'         -37.693     39.196    -0.96165    3286        0.33629     -114.55      39.158
    'GOLD_GOLD 3'         -116.48     41.092     -2.8346    3286      0.0046168     -197.05      -35.91
    'GOLD_GOLD 4'         -149.93      47.12     -3.1819    3286      0.0014769     -242.32     -57.542
    'MMRC_MMRC 1'         -87.613     33.471     -2.6175    3286      0.0088972     -153.24     -21.986
    'MMRC_MMRC 2'         -118.45      35.62     -3.3255    3286     0.00089232     -188.29     -48.615
    'MMRC_MMRC 3'         -186.65     39.023      -4.783    3286     1.8032e-06     -263.16     -110.13
    'MMRC_MMRC 4'          -237.1     51.409     -4.6121    3286     4.1385e-06      -337.9     -136.31
    'Sex_Male'          53.543     22.806      2.3478    3286       0.018945       8.828      98.258
    'Age'                  -10.17     1.3294     -7.6502    3286     2.6191e-14     -12.776     -7.5635
    'BMI'                 -29.448     2.0287     -14.516    3286     2.5289e-46     -33.426     -25.471

Random effects covariance parameters (95% CIs):
Group: Subject (805 Levels)
    Name1                Name2                Type         Estimate    Lower     Upper 
    '(Intercept)'        '(Intercept)'        'std'        281.29      266.17    297.27

Group: Error
    Name             Estimate    Lower     Upper 
    'Res Std'        195.29      189.93    200.79
```

Could you help me to interpret it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a less non descriptive title.

Comment: @jona I tried...please feel free to edit..

Comment: I'm having some difficulties interpreting the output. In the formula it clearly says that you use var_night, but I can't find it in the list of fixed effects. And in that list, there is Group, which I cannot see in the formula. Also, your Group variable should probably be used as a categorical variable and not a continuous one. I don't think that random effects are tested for significance, at least they're not in R and I haven't read about it being done.

Comment: Hi Jonas! Group is Var_night (I forgot to change it in the post). Why do you think that it would be better to use a categorical variable? unfortunately I couldn't find an explanation of the output in the matlab help
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlme.html

Comment: Ah, I see. Forget about using Group as a categorical variable, I didn't realize it was the same as var_night. Var_night seems to have the effect that one unit of change in var_night changes var_day with -0.37.7 units, with the standard error 0.05 and it's highly significant as p = 9.7e-13. The confidence intervals are to the right, -0.46 to -0.26. The other fixed effects are interpreted in the same way.. For the random effects I'm not entirely sure, but I think that Estimate refers to the estimated variance among subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the causality might go both ways, and if you just study the association between var_day and var_night, you won't be able to say anything about the causality. I don't think that this can be addressed in a regression analysis such as logistic regression or multiple regression.

Perhaps it would be possible using structural equations, but I don't know enough about those models to be certain. Another member gave you a hint about a model for comparing time series in this way, but I can't recall the name of that analysis model. Anyway, I think you have far too few observations per individual to do that kind of analysis.

But if you're satisfied with identifying an association between var_day and var_night, you can use a regression model. If the dependent variable (var_day?) is approximately normally distributed, it makes sense to use a linear mixed model, so that you can take the repeated measures into account. The "mixed" indicates that there is a random effect, which is the subject in this case to account for the correlation between the different var_day measurements within each subject. The equation, using R notation, might then be:

```
library(lme4)
lmer (Var_day ~ Var_night + Age + Sex + BMI + factor(Group) + (1|Subject_id))
```

You might also consider an effect of time on the dependent variable: perhaps the subjects may get more tired for each day they participate in the study? Then you might add Day as another random effect:

```
lmer (Var_day ~ Var_night + Age + Sex + BMI + factor(Group) + (1|Subject_id) + (1|Day))
```

Of course, you would need to check to see if the assumption of a linear effect of Age, BMI and Var_night is reasonable.

But as I said, this will say nothing about the direction of the causality. If that's what you're after, you'll have to try something else.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for the answer! Can you correct me if I am wrong?
the first model that you wrote is a linear mixed-effects model for the variable measured during the day, with fixed effects for variable night, age, sex, bmi, group, and uncorrelated random effect for intercept  grouped by the subject IDs.

Comment: How should I interpret the fact that the random effect is significant? What can I say?

Comment: please have a look at the edited part of the question..